# Region R is enclosed by the lines $y=1$, $x=4$, and the curve $y=\sqrt{x}$. Rotation around x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

To be clear, I know how to do this problem using the washer method. I am trying to solve it using cylindrical shells. Here is what I have so far:

$2\pi \int_{1}^{2} y*y^2 dy$

$2\pi \int_{1}^{2} y^3 dy$

I get $15/2\pi$ as my final answer. the correct answer is supposed to be $9/2 * \pi$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't said what the question is. Are you trying to calculate the volume of this solid, perhaps? The surface area? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating the wrong region, draw a picture! Note that you should be looking at $4-y^{2}$ instead and indeed
$$2\pi\int_{1}^{2}y(4-y^{2}) \ dy =\frac{9\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Okay, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Disc Method**
[image]
$$
\begin{aligned}
\textrm{  Volume of the hollow solid }=& \pi \int_1^4(\sqrt{x})^2 d x-3 \pi(1)^2 \\
= & \pi\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_1^4-3 \pi \\
= & \frac{15 \pi}{2}- 3 \pi \\
= & \frac{9 \pi}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$